# Sitecore Scheduled task runs on startup

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, scheduler-job

I'm using Sitecore 9.3, I have a custom scheduled task for rebuilding the Sitecore search index at night.

My project is hosted on Azure environment, I noticed that if I restart the CM app service then the task gets triggered and rebuilds the index as a result.

I don't want that, I tried to reproduce the issue on my machine, but it didn't happen.

Schedule time is:
`20210803T235900||127|23:59:00`

Comment: Does it happen on restart of app service by clicking stop and start from `portal.azure.com`? I cannot think of any reason. More probable is that the job schedule item is synchronized and "Last Run" field is either cleared or set to an old date.

Comment: It happened yes after clicking restart on portal.azure.com.
Last Run field is not cleared, it was older date, because the task were run at this date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore's built-in **Tasks -> Schedulers** functionality works well when you need to execute a task occasionally, but it becomes problematic if you require to run some routine at a certain time every day.

You can schedule a task to run every 24 hours, but you cannot ensure that it will run at exact the same time every day because of the interval-based nature of the scheduled execution.

Task schedule in Sitecore is based on the interval execution, not on the absolute time. Sitecore periodically performs a check for any tasks that are due to run. Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute is defined in Sitecore config file, see `scheduling -> frequency` setting.

Therefore, it is almost impossible to schedule a task to execute at the specific hour and minute of a day.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I think it happened randomly after restarting the CM server